# in IB how do I get a subview to stay at the same size as it's parent when I resize the parent?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

In Interface Builder I have one parent view and a subview under this.

I would like to have it so that when I'm working in IB if I move/change the position of the parent view, that the subview moves with it so it continues to be the same size & shape.

Is there a way to do this?

Note I'm talking about use of IB in design mode (i.e. I'm not talking about once the program is running and the ability to be able to change position etc via code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHeck out the `AutoResizingMask`.

Comment: +1 Use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Comment: but this seems to not work in design mode? i.e. I was after something that straight away it would (in IB) auto-resize it to keep it the same size as the parent.  I do notice that the "Arrange" drop down list and selection of "fill container vertically" & horizontally works ok, but only once when you do it.  I'm effectively after this but happening automatically each time I change the size of the parent.

Comment: you need to use the AutoResizingMasks. You can also do this in code.

Comment: It must work in both design and run mode. You should check your parent view as well. It should be work. What exactly you have can you post image here ? what controls are you using.

Comment: In IB I have (a) top view - UIView, then (b) parent view - UIView, then some subviews which includes (c) custom view which is UIImageView with mode aspectfit.  Note I've laid these views out so they are each within each other with a bit of space around them (i.e. they are not close to being the correct size).  When I click on the autosizing lines the UIImageView doesn't resize at all.

Answer (score 6):

In Interface Builder (IB) You need to select all the Autoresize lines. See circle in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: but this seems to not work in design mode? i.e. I was after something that straight away it would (in IB) auto-resize it to keep it the same size as the parent.  I do notice that the "Arrange" drop down list and selection of "fill container vertically" & horizontally works ok, but only once when you do it.  I'm effectively after this but happening automatically each time I change the size of the parent.